# VBA - Ler um arquivo .TXT e manipular as linhas dele

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou tentando fazer um gerador de Query usando o Excel (VBA), mas não estou conseguindo manipular alguns dados dentro de um arquivo .sql.

Ex.:

```
Select *
From Tabela t
Where t.id = 1
<PROP>
```

Toda vez que ele encontrar uma linha que esteja escrito PROP ele deverá trocar pelo valor que está na célula H3, e no final salvar o arquivo.

Já consigo fazer ele ler o arquivo até o final, mas não sei alterar o valor PROP pelo o valor que está na celula H3.

Para ficar melhor explicado.

```
Dim strTextLine
Dim strTextFile
Dim intFileNumber

'Nome completo do arquivo a ser aberto
strTextFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Query.sql"

'Criar numeração
intFileNumber = 1

'Criar conexão com o arquivo txt
Open strTextFile For Input As #intFileNumber  '<- Input ou Append?

'Loop para percorrer as linhas do arquivo até o seu final
Do While Not EOF(intFileNumber)
   Line Input #intFileNumber, strTextLine
   If (strTextLine = "<PROP>") Then
       'como faço para alterar a tag <PROP> por um valor que está em uma variavel?
       ' Já consegui encontrar a linha só não sei como altero o valor no arquivo.
    End If
Loop

'Fechar a conexão com o arquivo
Close #intFileNumber
```

Atenciosamente,

Answer (score 1):

Como ainda não consigo fazer comentários, deixo aqui uma sugestão que penso que te pode ajudar.

```
Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="PROP", Replacement:=Range("H1").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Defines as colunas onde o texto ter que ser localizado e corres a macro.

Comment: Não entendi R. Galamba.

Answer (score 1):

Estou a supor que o ficheiro .sql já existe. Ajuste o código de acordo com a necessidade.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SqlMacro()
Dim ficheiro As String
Dim texto As String
Dim textline As String
Dim celula As String

    On Error GoTo Erro

    'localização do ficheiro
    ficheiro = "C:\teste.sql"

    'abre o ficheiro
    Open ficheiro For Input As #1

    'lê o ficheiro
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        texto = texto & textline
    Loop
    'fecha o ficheiro
    Close #1

    'adquire o conteúdo da célula H3, na folha 1
    celula = Sheets(1).Cells(3, 8)  '(linha, coluna)
    'faz a troca de <PROP> pelo conteúdo da célula
    texto = Replace(texto, "<PROP>", celula)

    'sobrescreve o ficheiro
    Open ficheiro For Output As #1
    Print #1, texto
    Close #1
    Exit Sub

Erro:
    'se houver algum erro, descreve-o
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```